# Calculating TPI (topographic position index) and TRI (topographic ruggedness index) in QGIS

Tags: raster, gdal, qgis-3, saga

I know there are similar questions regarding the computation of TPI and TRI. However, I found myself a bit lost in how to perform the calculation in QGIS. So, I have DEM, and the projection is set to EPSG:3857. I have found three algorithms to perform the analysis (GDAL, SAGA and raster terrain analysis). I want somebody to clarify which algorithm is using which methodology. I know Wilson's (2007) and Raley's (1999) methods. My goal is to compute TRI for the European mainland.

Comment: The QGIS website for TRI cites this paper:  Riley et al. (1999).  After a search on Google Scholar this link was returned for the citation:  http://download.osgeo.org/qgis/doc/reference-docs/Terrain_Ruggedness_Index.pdf.  Apparently the algorithm is the DOCELL method which is detailed in the methods.  Here are some citations for TPI:  https://landscapearchaeology.org/2019/tpi/ thay may be useful.

Comment: You certainly don't want to be doing any spatial modelling in Web Mercator (3857) -- all the distances would be wrong.

Comment: Which coordinate reference system would you use?

Comment: Anybody has more suggestions on this topic? I would like to know which CRS to use, which algorithm to use. Thanks a lot

Comment: @Vince, could you please elaborate further on which CRS should be used to compute TRI? And which algorithm should be used?